Размещения сервера(express.js) на vps и обращение к нему через сайт(fetch)
Разрабатывал локально сайт, простой сервер с эндпоинтами на express.js и запросы к ним через fetch на чистом js. выложил сайт на VPS, без домена, просто ip, я правильно понимаю, что в запросе вместо localhost:3000/endpoint теперь нужно прописывать ip/endpoint? просто если так делать, то выскакивает cors какие-бы заголовки не прописывал никак не могу решить проблему, выдает Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://айпи:3000/register. (Причина: не удалось выполнить запрос CORS). Код состояния: (null).
app.use(cors({
        origin: 'http://мой айпи',
        methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS'],
        allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
}));

const response = await fetch('http://мой айпи:3000/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });

